# Passkeys aren't allowed on this account when trying to configure on iPhone

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, security, passwords, g-suite-administrator

I want to configure a [passkey for my Google account](https://security.googleblog.com/2023/05/so-long-passwords-thanks-for-all-phish.html?m=1).

On my iPhone I

1. surf to https://myaccount.google.com
2. click the Security tab
3. click Passkeys
4. I'm shown a screen stating "Passkeys aren't allowed on this account. Contact your admin for help"

[image: Passkeys aren't allowed on this account]

This is a Google Workspace account, and I'm the administrator. But I can't find any passkeys settings on https://admin.goolge.com

This is happening for all users in my Google Workspace.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Reading their announcement @ [https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/the-beginning-of-the-end-of-the-password/](https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/the-beginning-of-the-end-of-the-password/) (Dated May 3) I can see that they don't yet have an option to enable passkeys for Google Workspaces. > For Google Workspace accounts, administrators will soon have the
> option to enable passkeys for their end-users during sign-in.

Comment: I closed this question because the referred article clearly says that the feature is available for personal accounts. The textual statement is "Starting today, you can create and use passkeys on your personal Google Account."

Comment: Besides being a question about using a webapp it should be relevant and interesting to be answered by experts. The goal is to build a knowledge base (something closer to Wikipedia than a help desk log). Something we have not done yet is to take advantage of [chat]. It is possible to add entries from RSS feeds automatically, but an audience should be willing to chat about posts like the one you referred to.